# How to find the 2nd and 4th search item on a line?

Tags: regex, search, vim

This is my text:

```
my text my text my text my text my text
my text my text my text my text my text
        |2|             |4|
```

I'm trying to match the 2nd and 4th item on all lines
in this case `my`

I was convinced that the code below would work and no matter what I change it does not work.

```
/^\(.\{-}\zs\(my\)\)\{2}\|^\(.\{-}\zs\(my\)\)\{4}
```

Can someone help me to find the error in the code? How can I match this item?

Comment: Is 4rd a corruption of 3rd or 4th?

Comment: also, whether it is 2nd and 3rd or 2nd and 4th, you don't have "my" on both places.

Comment: @dotNET, I'm not sure if I understand your question.. but the 2nd `my` and the 4th `my` on every line.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these matches? Highlight them? Copy/delete/edit them? Stop at them when you press `n` for next match? Something else?

Comment: @Ben, Sometimes copy, sometimes, delete them. I already have a few functions to do this but first I must be enable to highlight them. Next match (n) must cycle through all matches in the entiere document.

Answer (score 2):

Testing this pattern, it only highlights the second match, and not the fourth. Swapping 2 and 4 in the regexp has the opposite effect. It seems that the second half is being ignored.

Replacing the second half with `text` does do what you think it does - highlights the second `my` and occurences of `text`. However this is not reusing text to match.

According to the vim manual,

> A pattern is one or more branches, separated by "\|".  It matches
>   anything that matches one of the branches.  Example: "foo\|beep"
>   matches "foo" and matches "beep".  If more than one branch matches,
>   the first one is used.

It would seem that once the beginning of a line is matched by the regexp, it is used and not available for further matching.

The best I can come up with is to match the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc. matches with `/^\(.\{-}\zs\(my\)\)\{2}\|\(.\{-}\zsmy\)\{2}` - deleting the `^` from the beginning of the second half, changing 4 to 2 so we can match after we've already matched using the first half at the beginning of the line. I can't find a way to avoid matching the 6th and subsequent matches - if we use `.*$` to eat the rest of the line, we have to put a `\ze` before it to avoid the rest of the line being highlighted, but it looks like vim jumps back to where the `\ze` was to continue looking for matches.

What you want to do may require too much context and state saved between matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into substituting, not just finding, you can use my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602)'s `:SubstituteSelected` command, which allows to specify the instances to replace. In your example, you'd apply this separately to each line (using `:global`), and specify the 2nd and 4th matches:

```
:%global/^/SubstituteSelected /my/your/g 2,4
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in finding first the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

`\v(.{-}\zs(my)){2}\ze%<33c`, which limits the search before the 33th column.